# Help me identify a movie about a woman with a vampire baby and a romance with her doctor?

Tags: story-identification, vampire

A woman gets a baby that is a vampire but she doesn't know it.

A doctor helps her a few times and they fall in love. I think the doctor is a vampire and he has an evil brother.

The movie is at least 17 years old.

Does anyone know the name of this?

Comment: Is this a short story, novel, comic, TV show, movie, what?

Comment: When did you read/watch it? Was it in English? Do you recall names/descriptions of characters?

Comment: it was a movie  ,  English my freind saw it 17years ago , and sadly no

Comment: "Doctor Baby 4 - Evil Twin Vampire Romance"

Answer (score 2):

I saw this movie as well. The doctor had long hair and the woman very short hair. I thought it was called "***Prince / Son of Darkness: To Die For***" or something like that, but I've never been able to find it.

Comment: [Son of Darkness: To Die for II](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TnFOc042Qw)?

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102961/

Comment: Seems like a match based on Wikipedia: _"There is **something wrong with Nina's adopted son** Tyler. The seductive **Dr. Max Schreck** knows a cure - fresh, young blood. Schreck, the original Prince of Darkness, has discovered that vampires can lead more normal lives by existing on his hospital's blood supply. Max attempts to seduce Nina into being his next victim, and together with his son Tyler they will rule over a new age of vampires. But **Tom, Max's jealous brother, has a plot of his own to destroy Max.**"_